# URL Rewrite subdomain with variables to regular domain with variables

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to get some help with this URL rewrite. I have already read multiple tutorials and documentation pages on how to do all this, but none of it makes sense to me. I also don't understand regular expression, so that doesn't help either. I have a semi working piece of code and just need help getting it working correctly.

I need: http://subdomain.domain.com?dl=2

to redirect to http://domain.com/subdomain.php?dl=2

The code I have is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !page.php
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?([^/]*)$ page.php?dl=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Which sends the variable but can't figure out the subdomain part. If anyone could please help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the `QUERY_STRING` as `RewriteRule` doesn't include it. In addition, your rule is not using the redirect flag `R`.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on

# First, check for the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]

# Then, check the query string - it should match digits (\d+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dl=\d+ [NC]

# Check if we are not at subdomain.php
# (This is redundant, but leaving it here in case you really need it)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain.php

# If all the above conditions are true, match a root-request
# and redirect to domain.com/subdomain.php with the query string
# Note: You don't need to actually specify the query string
#       in the destination URI - Apache will automatically
#       hand it over upon redirect (using the R flag).
#       The only time this is not the case is when you
#       either add the QSD flag, or append the destination
#       URI with a question mark.
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/subdomain.php [R=302,L]
```

The above will redirect http://subdomain.domain.com/?dl=2 to http://domain.com/subdomain.php?dl=2. If you would like to make the redirect permanent and cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.